# Windows のコマンドプロンプトで Rails をインストールするとエラーが発生します。解決策を教えてください。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Windows のコマンドプロンプトで Rails をインストールすると、以下のエラーが発生します。解決策を教えてください。

OSはwindows10homeで、Rubyのバージョンは、ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x64-mingw32]です。
RubyInstallerでは、Ruby 2.6.3-1 (x64) からダウンロードしました。
ridk installでは3番のコマンドを入力しました。

```sh
$ gem install rails -v 5.0.3

Fetching activesupport-5.0.3.gem
Fetching tzinfo-1.2.5.gem
Fetching concurrent-ruby-1.1.5.gem
Fetching nokogiri-1.10.3-x64-mingw32.gem
Fetching i18n-0.9.5.gem
Fetching mini_portile2-2.4.0.gem
Fetching thread_safe-0.3.6.gem
Fetching rails-dom-testing-2.0.3.gem
Fetching crass-1.0.4.gem
Fetching loofah-2.2.3.gem
Fetching rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.4.gem
Fetching erubis-2.7.0.gem
Fetching builder-3.2.3.gem
Fetching actionview-5.0.3.gem
Fetching rack-2.0.7.gem
Fetching rack-test-0.6.3.gem
Fetching actionpack-5.0.3.gem
Fetching sprockets-3.7.2.gem
Fetching sprockets-rails-3.2.1.gem
Fetching method_source-0.9.2.gem
Fetching thor-0.20.3.gem
Fetching railties-5.0.3.gem
Fetching websocket-extensions-0.1.3.gem
Fetching websocket-driver-0.6.5.gem
Fetching nio4r-2.3.1.gem
Fetching actioncable-5.0.3.gem
Fetching globalid-0.4.2.gem
Fetching activejob-5.0.3.gem
Fetching mini_mime-1.0.1.gem
Fetching mail-2.7.1.gem
Fetching actionmailer-5.0.3.gem
Fetching arel-7.1.4.gem
Fetching activemodel-5.0.3.gem
Fetching activerecord-5.0.3.gem
Fetching rails-5.0.3.gem
Successfully installed concurrent-ruby-1.1.5
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.6
Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.5
Successfully installed i18n-0.9.5
Successfully installed activesupport-5.0.3
Successfully installed mini_portile2-2.4.0
Nokogiri is built with the packaged libraries: libxml2-2.9.9, libxslt-1.1.33, zlib-1.2.11, libiconv-1.15.
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.10.3-x64-mingw32
Successfully installed rails-dom-testing-2.0.3
Successfully installed crass-1.0.4
Successfully installed loofah-2.2.3
Successfully installed rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.4
Successfully installed erubis-2.7.0
Successfully installed builder-3.2.3
Successfully installed actionview-5.0.3
Successfully installed rack-2.0.7
Successfully installed rack-test-0.6.3
Successfully installed actionpack-5.0.3
Successfully installed sprockets-3.7.2
Successfully installed sprockets-rails-3.2.1
Successfully installed method_source-0.9.2
Successfully installed thor-0.20.3
Successfully installed railties-5.0.3
Successfully installed websocket-extensions-0.1.3
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
**ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.**

current directory: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.6.5/ext/websocket-driver
C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20190602-22760-1qkmzx8.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.6.5/ext/websocket-driver
make "DESTDIR=" clean
current directory: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.6.5/ext/websocket-driver
make "DESTDIR="
make failedNo such file or directory - make "DESTDIR="

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.6.5 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/websocket-driver-0.6.5/gem_make.out
```

ridk versionコマンドを入力すると、以下のようになります。

```sh
ruby:
  path: C:/Ruby26-x64
  version: 2.6.3
  platform: x64-mingw32
ruby_installer:
  package_version: 2.6.3-1
  git_commit: 779b05c
msys2:
  path: C:\msys64
  title: MSYS2 64bit
  version: '20190524'
cc: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 8.3.0
os: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.765]
```

ridk exec gcc --versionコマンドを入力すると以下のようになります。

```sh
gcc (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

エラーメッセージにある"C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/websocket-driver-0.6.5/gem_make.out"のファイルの全文は以下のようになります。

```sh
current directory: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.6.5/ext/websocket-driver
C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20190602-8088-1kwkdar.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.6.5/ext/websocket-driver
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.6.5/ext/websocket-driver
make "DESTDIR="
generating websocket_mask-x64-mingw32.def
compiling websocket_mask.c
linking shared-object websocket_mask.so

current directory: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.6.5/ext/websocket-driver
make "DESTDIR=" install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 websocket_mask.so ./.gem.20190602-8088-wzq5uh
```

Comment: OSとRubyのバージョンを追記してください。また、Rubyはインストール方法(パス的にRubyInstallerだと思われますが、RubyInstallerにも種類があり、どれを入れたのか)も追記してください。もし、RubyInstallerであれば、`ridk install`を実行したのか、実行するときにMSYS2環境について他に用意するなどしてるかなどを追記してください。`ridk install`を実行済みであれば、`ridk version`と`ridk exec gcc --version`の結果を追記してください。

Comment: コメントではなく、質問に追記してください。質問は「編集」からいつでも編集できます。質問に書いてある方が、みんなが読みやすく、回答も得やすくなります。

Comment: エラーメッセージにある"C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/websocket-driver-0.6.5/gem_make.out"の内容を確認してください。もし、そのファイルに書いてある内容の意味がわからない(つまり、読んでも自力で解決できない)場合は、メッセージの全文を質問に追記してください。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。ファイルを確認したところ、内容がわかりませんでした。どうか解読の方よろしくお願いします。

Comment: コンパイル自体は成功しているっぽいですし、私の環境でうまくいった場合と同じメッセージ内容でした。その"gem_make.out"があったフォルダに"websocket_mask.so"もあると思います。ちょっとよくわからない感じです。あと、MSYS2はRubyInstallerとは別にインストールしておいたであってますでしょうか？

Comment: "websocket_mask.so"ファイルあります。初め、MSYS2と同時にRubyInstaller2をインストールしましたが、その後改めてRubyInstallerをインストールしました。